# Ошибка SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \xXX escape на на Python kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, kivy

Пишу калькулятор на python kivy и вылетает такая ошибка:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/egor/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-09-07_59.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
     Main().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 599, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 401, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 514, in parse
     rule.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 261, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 261, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 261, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 257, in precompile
     x.precompile()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 179, in precompile
     self.co_value = eval(value)
   File "<string>", line 1
 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \xXX escape
```

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout



class Root(PageLayout):
    pass


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()


Main().run()
```

main.kv:

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    #padding_x: 5

<Root>:
    id: field
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        TextInput:
            id : CalcPanel
        GridLayout:
            id : keyboardCalc
            cols:5
            Button:
                text: 'sin'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'sin('
            Button:
                text: 'cos'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'cos('
            Button:
                text: 'tan'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'tg('
            Button:
                text: 'AC'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text ='0'
            Button:
                id : delete
                text: 'del'
            Button:
                text: 'X^y'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += ' ** '
            Button:
                text: 'sqrt'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'sqrt('
            Button:
                text: '!'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'factorial('
            Button:
                text: '('
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '('
            Button:
                text: ')'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += ')'
            Button:
                text: '1\x'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '1/('
            Button:
                text: 'Pi'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'pi'
            Button:
                text: 'e'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += 'e'
            Button:
                text: '%'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '%'
            Button:
                text: '/'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '/'
            Button:
                text: '0'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '0'
            Button:
                text: '7'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '7'
            Button:
                text: '8'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '8'
            Button:
                text: '9'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '9'
            Button:
                text: '*'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '*'
            Button:
                text: '.'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '.'
            Button:
                text: '4'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '4'
            Button:
                text: '5'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '5'
            Button:
                text: '6'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '6'
            Button:
                text: '-'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '-'
            Button:
                text: ''
            Button:
                text: '1'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '1'
            Button:
                text: '2'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '2'
            Button:
                text: '3'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '3'
            Button:
                text: '+'
                on_press:
                    CalcPanel.text += '+'
    Button:
        id:button
```

при этом если удалить виджет keyboardCalc (который с кучей кнопок) то ошибка не вылетает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так и написано `\xXX`, или вы сами на иксы заменили?

Comment: так и написано ничего не менял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строке: `'1\x'`

Обратный слэш внутри строк в Python имеет особое значение, см. например тут: [Работа со строками в Python: литералы](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-literaly-strok.html), раздел ***Экранированные последовательности - служебные символы***.

В данной строке Python его распознает как часть последовательности типа `'\xDE'` (где DE - шестнадцатеричный код символа), о чем и написано в ошибке: "truncated \xXX escape" - примерно переводится как "обрезанная экранированная последовательность \xXX".

Проблема решается или экранированием слеша `'1\\x'`, либо использованием "сырых" строк (строки с `r` перед первой кавычкой) - `r'1\x'` (про сырые строки см. по ссылке выше, раздел ***"Сырые" строки - подавляют экранирование***).

Или же заменить обратный слэш на прямой: похоже, у вас предполагается операция деления единицы на какое-то число.